# How to get a subset of a dataframe which only has elements which appear in the set more than once in R

Tags: r

I have a set of data which I would like a subset of. I would like the subset defined as those rows with a value for variable X which appears more than once. Variable X is a string.

So, for example, if x consisted of ('help','me,'me','with','this','this'), it would return the rows with the x values ('me','me','this,'this').

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
x <- c('help','me','me','with','this','this')
x[duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE) | duplicated(x)]
```

Comment: You are pretty awesome. you know that, right?

Thanks for teaching me the duplicated command!